# Removing elements from plot (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

folks. I have been working on an application with MFCC for voice recognition. At first, having recorded my voice signal (with 24000 samples), it goes through this high pass filter:

```
for n=2:length(x)
    y(n) = x(n) - 0.95*x(n-1);
end
```

After that, I must resample this signal with a period of 20ms, meaning that I should eliminate the unused samples and retrieve the ones with index 160, 320, 480 and so on. Thus, I have used the following piece of code:

```
for n=1:length(y)
    if (rem(n,160)) == 0
        y(n) = y(n);
    else
        y(n) = [];
    end
end
```

However, I did not have any success with this last part (MATLAB says Matrix index is out of range for deletion). What should I do?

Comment: `if (rem(n,160)) == 0` should be if (rem(n,160) == 0). Also, you remove the element inside loop!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the code is you remove the elements of `y` inside the loop and loop on the length of the old `y`.
You can do the whole of the second part using the following code:

```
y = y(160:160:length(y));
```

This code get the all index of y which are dividable by 160.
However, you should be aware of changing the size of the `y` after this operation.

Comment: The thing is: I need to delete all the other samples. This way nothing has actually changed.

Comment: nope. you're wrong. you can check the size of the `y`.